# Interpreting I/O Transformation Matrix in Convolution

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

I've been reading [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1) on convolutional neural networks (I'm a beginner) - and I'm stuck at a point.

[image]

What I understand: We have a 4x4 input, and want to transform it to a 2x2 grid. I'm visualising this as a kernel sliding over the 4x4 grid, with just the right number of strides, so as to get 4 outputs which constitute the 2x2 grid (there are animations right above this part of the page in the link attached). The model chooses to represent the 4x4 grid as a vector of length 16. Also, the 4x16 transformation matrix when pre-multiplied to the input vector, produces the output vector, which is mapped back to a 2D grid. *Is this right?*

Moving on, another screenshot from the same page-
[image]

Is it that both the matrices are really the same, and a lot of weights just happen to be zero in the weight matrix, which is what the second matrix is depicting? In that case even, why so many zeros?

P.S. Thanks a lot for being so patient and reading to the end of this post, I really appreciate it. I'm a beginner, and really interested in these topics, and I'm self studying from various online resources - hence, any help is appreciated. I hope this is the right platform for this post.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Although I acknowledge you are confused, please, ask one question per post! See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (specifically, the section **notes**) for more details. Please, edit your post to ask only 1 question. Ask other questions in their separate post. I will be happy to answer your question, if I am able to. This is one of the reasons why you should ask one question per post: maybe someone is able to answer one question, but not the others. Btw, your questions are very interesting!

Comment: Maybe later I will provide a formal answer. Meanwhile, to provide you with some info, have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039201/3924118). This should help you with the second part of your post. Btw, once you have an answer to your questions, you can also answer your own questions!